# ReferenceError: undefinedPopper is not defined

Tags: webpack, bootstrap-4, popper.js

I didn't find issues on this subject, however, after spending some time, I'm still stuck on this.

While I'm working on a project with:

this package.json

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
        "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring": "^6.23.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
        "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
        "browser-sync": "^2.23.6",
        "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.2",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
        "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
        "expose-loader": "^0.7.5",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
        "fast-sass-loader": "^1.4.1",
        "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
        "hard-source-webpack-plugin": "^0.6.4",
        "jquery-bem-utils": "^0.0.8",
        "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
        "path": "^0.12.7",
        "postcss-cssnext": "^3.1.0",
        "postcss-csso": "^3.0.0",
        "postcss-loader": "^2.1.2",
        "purify-css": "^1.2.5",
        "purifycss-webpack": "^0.7.0",
        "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
        "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
        "svgo": "^1.0.5",
        "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.4",
        "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
        "webpack": "^4.1.1",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.0.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.1",
        "webpack-spritesmith": "^0.4.0"
    },
    ...
    "dependencies": {
        "babel-core": "6",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
        "bootstrap-growl-ifightcrime": "^1.1.0",
        "bootstrap-slider": "^10.0.0",
        "bootstrap-tabcollapse": "^0.2.6",
        "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30000697",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "photoswipe": "^4.1.2",
        "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
        "sidr": "^2.2.1",
        "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
        "twbs-pagination": "^1.4.1"
    }
}
```

this webpack.config.js:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    '$': 'jquery',
    'jQuery': 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
  }),
```

If I remove my `node_modules/` then do a `yarn install && yarn start`, all is working as supposed.
If I stop `yarn start` and rerun it, I got this error:

`ReferenceError: undefinedPopper is not defined` which leads to `webpack://app/./node_modules/popper.js/dist/esm/popper.js?:2534:30` => `__webpack_exports__["default"] = (undefinedPopper);`

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, any idea?